# How to create schema in Oracle and table spaces?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I create user(schema) in oracle. like this

```
create user EMP_DB identified by netsolpk account unlock;
```

But when i tried login through schema name and password, login failed. Below is the error message.

```
user EMP_DB lacks create session privilage; login denied.
```

I've not created any tablespaces.

For this, do I need to create any tablespace? If needed, how to create a tablespace?
And what more things are required for creating a schema in oracle 11g.

Please help me and give me step by step procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The error `user EMP_DB lacks create session privilage; login denied` indicates that you need privilege to create a session. So you need to grant the appropriate privilege like,

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO emp_db;
```

Or You can go with granting the roles(group of privileges), `CONNECT` and `RESOURCE`.

`CONNECT` role has only `CREATE SESSION` privilege.

`RESOURCE` has the following privilges,

```
CREATE TRIGGER
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE TYPE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE CLUSTER
CREATE OPERATOR
CREATE INDEXTYPE
CREATE TABLE
```

To find these `PRIVILEGES` of a `ROLE`, You can query the `DBA_SYS_PRIVS` table with a query like this:

```
SELECT grantee, privilege, admin_option 
FROM   DBA_SYS_PRIVS 
WHERE  grantee='RESOURCE';
```

Also to use the existing tablespace `USERS`, You can create a user with `QUOTA UNLIMITED` statement like,

```
CREATE USER emp_db IDENTIFIED BY netsolpk QUOTA UNLIMITED on USERS;
```

Answer (score 0):

the fastest, quickest way to create a new user with privileges is

```
grant connect, resource to NewUser_name identified by NewUser_password;
```

by this command you will be sure that errors like above will not displayed.